# use css inside date fields in Symfony

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am making some design in my application and I would like to use css to change position of a **date** in **Symfony**. It's type is `DateType`. I got different **ids** so I do a thing like that:

```
 #date_year {
   top: 20px;
  }

#date_month {
   top: 20px;
  }

#date_day {
   top: 20px;
  }
```

The dates change places but there is a **-** separting them who is still on the same place. My code in the `twig.html` file is this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.date, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
```

Another problem I got I would not want to use **form-control** in this case. But if I do not the date appears automatically in the next line. So to summarize I would to have this:

```
  myDate:  2017   -  08   -  11 (in the same line of course and the type of myDate is DateType(Symfony)).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the date in Twig's date.

For display;

`form.date("d")` - `form.date("m")` - `form.date("Y")`

For real value;

`{{ form_widget(form.date, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}`

You can hide the read value from user and you can display the separated values to user.

Doc :
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html#date

Comment: I don't understand the answer. How do you propose to change in my file twig.hrml (responsable for creation of a form). If I do this in it form.date("d") - form.date("m") - form.date("Y") I will got an error @Mert